# Upper bound on differences of consecutive zeta zeros

Tags: number-theory, complex-analysis, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

The average gap $\delta_n=|\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n|$ between consecutive zeros $(\beta_n+\gamma_n i,\beta_{n+1}+\gamma_{n+1}i)$ of Riemann's zeta function is $\frac{2\pi}{\log\gamma_n}.$ There are many papers giving lower bounds to
$$
\limsup_n\ \delta_n\frac{\log\gamma_n}{2\pi}
$$
unconditionally or on RH or GRH. (The true value is believed to be $+\infty.$) I'm interested in an upper bound on the smaller quantity $\delta_n$. I asked the [question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84989/upper-bounds-on-the-difference-of-consecutive-zeta-zeros) but have not yet found an effective bound. Both unconditional results and those relying on the RH are interesting.

Comment: Mind including a link to the MO question?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84989/upper-bounds-on-the-difference-of-consecutive-zeta-zeros

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two things:

1) On RH you have the clean bound
$$
\delta_n \leq \pi ( 1 + o(1)) / \log\log \gamma_n
$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$, 
due to Goldston and Gonek. If the $o(1)$ bothers you, you can remove it
by re-working the details in their (short) paper (see http://www.math.sjsu.edu/~goldston/article38.pdf in particular see Corollary 1).

Unconditionally, you have the point-wise bound due to Littlewood,
$$
\delta_n \leq C / \log\log\log \gamma_n
$$
I am not aware of anybody working out the explicit value of the constant $C$ in this case.

2) You can get better bounds if you are interested in bounds valid for ``most'' zeros. For example it is known that
$$
\sum_{T \leq n \leq 2T} \delta_n^{2k} \asymp T (\log T)^{-2k}
$$
This allows you to get good bounds for most $\delta_n$'s which are as good as 
$\Psi(\gamma_n) / \log \gamma_n$ with a $\Psi(x)$ going to infinity arbitrarily slowly.

Comment: Come on give me points people, I worked on that answer and I answered his question!

Comment: Let's get the points flowing

Comment: Voting is a capricious thing.

Comment: Very nice! Absolutely deserving of the points. I am looking at extremal behavior of the gaps, so the first part is what interests me. I had not seen the paper.

Comment: @ blabler and robjohn :
How is it known : the equation from 2) with the sigma ? 
Voting capricious ? I disagree.
The entire MSE is based upon voting !
And I feel sorry for blabler.
He deserves more votes and I am also sorry for me.
Why ? Because I lost a bounty to this question and he missed my  bounty , so we both lost !
Now that bounty thing did not work and it has failed for me before , now that is capricious !
Are you in a bad mood perhaps ?
Welcome to MSE blabler !

Comment: @blabler.  Can you give the reference for Littlewood's result?