# Asymptotics of the differences between successive zeta zeros

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

Does anyone know what the asymptotic of the differences between successive zeta zeros is?

[image]

## Update

It appears that $\zeta(n)$ is not a bad asymptotic, when the data range is stretched:

[image]

```
r = 3000; Show[ListPlot[(Differences[Table[Im[N[ZetaZero[n]]],{n, 1, r}]]), 
m = 100; ListLinePlot[Table[Zeta[n], {n, 0, Log[r], 0.01}], 
DataRange -> {-r/\[Pi], r}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

(as is $\pi/\log\log\gamma_n$ following on from the link suggested by [barto](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/43288/barto)). I don't know how to write this mathematically though.

Comment: Related: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95693/upper-bound-on-differences-of-consecutive-zeta-zeros?rq=1) and [this](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/84989/upper-bounds-on-the-difference-of-consecutive-zeta-zeros) linked question on MO.

Comment: The best possible asymptotic to the Riemann zeta zeros, as pointed out by reuns, is the functional inverse of the Riemann Siegel theta function. As a Mathematica program that would be: Round[Table[ N[InverseFunction[RiemannSiegelTheta][Pi*(n - 1/2)], 30], {n, 0, 12}]]