# What is the effective lower bound on gaps between zeta zeros?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

In this question here:
[Upper bound on differences of consecutive zeta zeros](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95693/upper-bound-on-differences-of-consecutive-zeta-zeros)
by Charles it is said that: "There are many papers giving lower bounds to:

$$\limsup_n\ \delta_n\frac{\log\gamma_n}{2\pi}$$

unconditionally or on RH or GRH." RH stands of course for the Riemann hypothesis.

Therefore I am asking: What is the best unconditional effective lower bound for gaps $$\delta_n=|\gamma_{n+1}-\gamma_n|$$ between consecutive non-trivial Riemann zeta function zeros?

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05350 http://www.crm.umontreal.ca/anatomie06/pdf/goldston1.pdf

Comment: http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2372402.pdf?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents. See paragraph below formula (2). There are a lot of questions here on lim inf with good answers BTW.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/a/226013/25104

Answer (score 4):

[In 2012 Feng and Wu showed](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X12000261) that $$\limsup_{n} \delta_n \frac{\log \gamma_n}{2\pi}\geq 2.7327.$$

Note however that the quantity $$\mu=\liminf_n\delta_n \frac{\log \gamma_n}{2\pi}$$ is far more interesting. Unconditionally, the best bound is $\mu<0.525396$ due to [this recent paper of Preobrazhenskii](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05350v1.pdf), however even under the Riemann Hypothesis this cannot be improved very much. Proving that $\mu<1/2$ would be a remarkable achievement, even under the Riemann hypothesis, as this would resolve the longstanding conjecture that there are no [Siegel Zeros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel_zero) for *any* Dirichlet L-function. This remarkable connection between the spacing of the zeros of $\zeta(s)$, and the properties of the zeros of *all* Dirichlet L-functions is known as the [Deuring–Heilbronn phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deuring%E2%80%93Heilbronn_phenomenon).

Comment: Since you know of the paper Feng and Wu, that I was aware of too, but I have not read in its entirety, What is meant with the phrase in the abstract: "...,we show that infinitely often consecutive non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta-function differ by at least..."? Does "infinitely often" equal always? Repeat of my question here: Is "infinitely often" the same as saying: "...consecutive non-trivial zeros of the Riemann zeta-function differ _always_ by at least..."

Comment: Also. I am not yet competent in understanding the notions "sup" and "inf".